# How to upload and store image in sencha touch 2.0.0

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I need to develop an app and in this app i need to upload and store the uploaded image on the server. i see on the form panel i didn't see the upload field as i use in the html.
please respond as soon as possible.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully uploaded an encoded string using the following example back in ST1.1.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'page.php',
    params: {
        id: 1
    },
    success: function(response){
        var text = response.responseText;
        // process server response here
    }
});
```